# Nginx proxy_pass not working for tomcat (404 not found error)

Tags: nginx, ionic-framework, tomcat7, proxypass

My angular app is running on  **localhost:3030** through **nginx**.

My rest service is running on tomcat **localhost:7001**

nginx-conf settings :

```
enter code here
 server { 
    server_name localhost;
        listen 3030; 

        location / { 
        root D:\Ionic_workspace\merigaadi\www;
        }
        location /app {

          proxy_pass   http://localhost:7001/;


        }                
       }
```

I have tried everything to fix...but didn't get any luck. I am getting the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3030/app/unauth/login/authenticate 404 (Not Found)

proxy_pass is not working
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: You may need a trailing slash on your location, like: `location /app/` if you want `proxy_pass http://localhost:7001/;` to rewrite the URI correctly.

Comment: I have already tried this.....anything else to resolve this

Comment: The 404 response is probably originating from the service running on 7001 (tomcat). Do you have tomcat logs which show you the URI causing the 404 response?

Comment: When i hit the url in browser i am getting the proper response

Comment: it is resolved...i was trying with the wrong path :p .....thanks for your efforts Richard.